# Make linking of questions a transitive relation

Tags: feature-request, exact-duplicates, linked-questions

Right now if $a$ is a dupe of $b$ and $b$ is marked as a dupe of $c$, then $a$ doesn't appear in the linked questions for $c$. It maybe helpful if question $c$ could inherit all the dupes from the questions which it is linked too.

Comment: I asked that like 8 years ago and they told me that some scc's are kinda large and could create pathological behaviours.

Comment: @Yorch What does SCC mean here?

Comment: strongly connected component.

Comment: I am sure we must have the technology now to do it@Yorch

Comment: maybe, maybe not cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion